# T-SQL - Customer Linking

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Please run the below code, these are all the same Customer because 2 of them have the same **TaxNumber** while another one matches one based on **CompanyName**. I need to link them all and set the **ParentCompanyID** based on who was created first. I am struggling to get them linked.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
  CustomerID        INT,
  CustomerName      VARCHAR(20),
  CustomerTaxNumber INT,
  CreatedDate       DATE
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES (8, 'Company PTY',1234, '2019-09-20'),
       (2, 'Company PT', 1234, '2019-09-24'),
       (3, 'Company PTY',NULL, '2019-09-29')

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Below is the result that I require....
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's great you've posted proper sample data, not so much the image as desired output (formatted text would be a better choice). However, with over 3k reputation points you should know [ask]. Please [edit] your post to include your current attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `case` expression with `first_value` can give you the desired results:

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerTaxNumber, CreatedDate,
        CASE WHEN  CustomerTaxNumber IS NULL THEN
            FIRST_VALUE(CustomerID) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerName ORDER BY CreatedDate)
        ELSE
            FIRST_VALUE(CustomerID) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerTaxNumber ORDER BY CreatedDate)
        END As ParentCompanyID

FROM #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
  CustomerID        INT,
  CustomerName      VARCHAR(20),
  CustomerTaxNumber INT,
  CreatedDate       DATE
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES (8, 'Company PTY',1234, '2019-09-20'),
       (2, 'Company PT', 1234, '2019-09-24'),
       (3, 'Company PTY',NULL, '2019-09-29')

SELECT DS.[CreatedDate] AS [FirstEntry]
      ,DS.[CustomerID] AS [ParentCompanyID]
      ,#Temp.*
FROM #Temp
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM #Temp
    ORDER BY CreatedDate
) DS


DROP TABLE #Temp
```

[image]

You are condition is pretty simple - get the first record. If you need to group the records in some way, you can add additional filtering in the `CROSS APPLY` clause.

Comment: Thanks, this does work for these records, but my table with have other results in there as well that does belong to this company. Example: (9, 'XXXX PTY',NULL, '2019-09-30')

Comment: @etienne The sample data in the question should have covered that.